# Можно сказать: "Зерно добродетели"?

Tags: выбор-слов

Можно сказать - зерно добродетели?

Answer (score 1):

Так говорят в *множественном* числе (**зёрна** добродетели) и очень редко,

> Дети, которые воспитываются в храме, непременно станут достойными
> православными христианами, будут сеять *зерна добродетели*, милосердия и
> любви.
>
> http://donetsk.church.ua/2017/07/25/letnie-zanyatiya-v-voskresnojj-shkole/

поскольку зёрна больше ассоциируются с урожаем, чем с посевом, а типичный религиозный контекст подобного словоупотребления - "**сеять** доброе", поэтому более распространено выражение "**семена добродетели**".

Comment: Можно и в единственном числе.  См. примеры: http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E7%E5%F0%ED%EE+%E4%EE%E1%F0%EE%E4%E5%F2%E5%EB%E8 ===

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что можно сказать: зерно истины, зерно сомнения, зерно мудрости, зерно добродетели ("сейте разумное, доброе, вечное").
Мне кажется, так вполне приемлемо говорить, когда имеется в виду конкретность или индивидуальность "передачи" этого зернышка (кусочка самого себя): от родителя — ребенку, от педагога — ученику, от духовного наставника — брату по вере.

*Так что мало усвоить хорошие манеры, мы должны заронить в сердца наших детей зерно добродетели, «заразить» их своим положительным примером.*
[Патриотизм и вера как осознанный выбор человека](http://www.skvk.org/50271)

*Зерно добродетели внутри вас, оно не имеет ничего общего с какими-то наградами. Она* [добродетель] *сама по себе награда.*
Беседы по книге Фридриха Ницше "Так говорил Заратустра"